# Sigma algebra generated by a function on measurable space generated by a set

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $f: X \to (Y, \Sigma)$ be a function from a set to a measurable space. The sigma-algebra generated by $f$, denoted $\sigma(f) := \{f^{-1}(A) \mid A \in \Sigma\}$, is the smallest sigma-algebra on $X$ making $f$ measurable.

Suppose now that the sigma-algebra $\Sigma$ on $Y$ is itself generated by a family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $Y$, i.e., $\Sigma = \sigma(\mathcal{F})$, which is the smallest sigma-algebra that contains every set of $\mathcal{F}$.

Under what conditions does it hold that

$$
\sigma(f) = \sigma(\{f^{-1}(A) \mid A \in \mathcal{F}\})?
$$

Comment: The property is used repeatedly when $Y$ is the reals and $\Sigma$ the sigma-algebra generated by the open sets, or perhaps more generally when $Y$ is a topological space and $\Sigma$ is the Borel sigma-algebra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal F$ be any family of subsets of $Y$. Since $\mathcal F \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal F)$, we have $ f^{-1}(\mathcal F) \subseteq f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal F)) $ and therefore
$$\sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal F)) \subseteq f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal F))$$ because $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal F))$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (easy to check). Conversly, define
$$ \mathcal E=\{E \subseteq Y : f^{-1}(E) \in \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal F))\} $$ One can easily check that $\mathcal E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (as preimage commutes with usual  operations on sets).  But $\mathcal E$ contains $\mathcal F$ so $\sigma(\mathcal F) \subseteq \mathcal E$. And this proves that $f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal F)) \subseteq \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal F))$ thus
$$ \sigma(f^{-1}(\mathcal F)) = f^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal F)) $$